# Fatal error while trying to share data to IMessage and Social Media Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm trying to make sharing button that shares image. Unfortunetely when I pick IMessage/Facebook/Messenger on popup i get 
"[]
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

Sharing to Notes/AirDrop/Mail works perfectly

```
@IBAction func share(){

    let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["test"], applicationActivities: nil)

    self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)   
}
```

Comment: This is your real code for this function?

Comment: yes, It didn't work with any arguments ("test" dont work also)

Comment: I suppose one possibility is your current ViewController is `nil` by the time you get to this call?  That's the only thing in the code you've posted that could be `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i discover that newest Xcode that I downloaded per days ago stopped printing all stack trace in console. I accesed stack by stack history on interface and discover that the error was caused because I had scrollView that moved to textfield in case keyboard would make that field invisible that had line;

```
let superView = selectedTextField.superview!
doSomething()
```

I changed it to:

```
if let superView = selectedTextField.superview {
     doSomething()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this on an iPad, you have to also specify as a `popoverPresentationController`.  Add this line before you present the `activityController`.

```
activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash
```